# "When"/"After" I heard him talk, I asked him if he got a cold - do they have a difference?

Tags: clauses

**Example 1**

> **When** I heard him talk, I asked him if he got a cold.

**Example 2**

> **After** I heard him talk, I asked him if he got a cold.

(1) Do they have a difference?

**Example 3**

> **When** I saw him stumble, I asked him if he was ok.

**Example 4**

> **When** he stumbled, I asked him if he was ok.

(2) Are verbs like "hear," "see," and "watch" used differently from normal verbs like "stumble" in a when-clause?

Comment: Logically, you would ask someone if he **had** a cold after hearing him speak; but in practice, **when** is much more natural.

Comment: The ***semantics*** of your examples are such that they're all unchanged by switching from ***when*** to ***after***. That's not the case with other *very similar* examples, such as ***When** the doorbell rang, I was in the shower* (where there's no way you could even use ***after*** at all, let alone while retaining the same meaning).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a difference between the first two sentences. The first would probably be more natural but either one is fine.

(Though, you would probably want to ask if he *had* a cold, rather than if he *got* a cold.)

The second two are also basically identical, and they both feel natural to me. (Although, the second sentence does of course imply that you saw the man stumble, rather than knowing about it in some other way.)